# When you return an evolved pokemon to your hand, and you put it back into play, do you have to evolve the pokemon again?

Tags: pokemon

For example, when amoonguss is returned to the hand, and you take it's stage one devolved form with it (foongus), and then you want to put it back into play, do you place amoonguss back in, or foongus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put them back into play the same as if they’d never been in.  You may return the Basic Pokémon to the field immediately if you want, but the Stage 1 must be placed on a Basic Pokémon that has been out since before the beginning of the turn.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! I'm still confused (I'm just a bit slow to understand things), so I'll follow up with this question. I'm editing this comment because I don't know how to reply on this site... 

Ok so what I'm confused is with the last sentence. So, I'll list the steps, and if you could correct where I'm wrong, that'd be great.

1.) Put amoongus and foongus back into hand

2.) when placing it back, you put the basic pokemon first (foongus) 

3.) Next turn, you evolve foongus into amoongus

Comment: Yes that’s correct - unless you have another foongus out already from a prior turn.  That foongus could be evolved this turn into amoongus.